# polynomial refactoring...can't resolve unknowns

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

I am trying to write an algorithm to factor the polynomial:
$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy+Dx+E = 0$
into two terms:
$(fx+gy+h)(jx+k)=0$

$x$ and $y$ are the variables;  $A$ through $F$ are provided; and I need to find $f$, $g$, $h$, $j$, and $k$.
So, this looks doable. I have five equations and five unknowns. However, in attempting to solve one of the equations collapses to:
$(AD/B)+(EB/D)=C$.
I attribute this to the fact that the original polynomial could be *normalized* to remove one of the coefficients (e.g. typically $A$ or $F$).

So now we have:
$x^2+B'xy+C'y+D'x+E' = 0$ or $A'x^2+B'xy+C'y+D'x+1 = 0$

but now, how to reduce this to the above:
$(fx+gy+h)(jx+k)=0$?
It seems that if I set normalize the original by $A$, then I could solve for the three remaining terms of $(x+gy+h)(x+k)=0$ but this is now three unknowns for four equations. Likewise if I normalize the input by F.

What's going on here?

Comment: This is over a field I assume?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is a field. $x$ and $y$ are independent variables in a Euclidean/Cartesian space.

Comment: Can you really factor like this? How would you do $x^2+y$? Neither $g=0$ nor $g\neq 0$ would work.

Comment: oh, that's a good point. In my particular case, I know that $B \ne 0$. but that doesn't really prove/disprove anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to factor $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy+Dx+E$ as $(fx+gy+h)(jx+k)$.

Note that when $x=\frac{-k}j$ the final expression is zero regardless of the value of $y$. If these two expressions really are the same, then this will also have to be true for the original expression.

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy+Dx+E = (Bx+C)y+Ax^2+Dx+E$

Clearly the only value of $x$ for which the $y$ disappears is $x=\frac{-C}B$. So we must have $\frac{-k}j=\frac{-C}B$, and furthermore, $Ax^2+Dx+E$ must be zero for that value of $x$.

Therefore, this factorisation is only possible if $A(\frac{C}B)^2+D\frac{-C}B+E=0$, which is when $AC^2-BCD+B^2E=0$

When that is the case, then you can divide $Ax^2+Dx+E$ by the factor $Bx+C$, to get the full factorisation that you want.

Answer (score 0):

By playing around with this in desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jf94mosesp), I have determined that this is not generally possible.
But why? and when?
Any insights?